# After finishing the iteration, call is not coming out of the while loop

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have this sample code for Apache kafka  consumer

```
public class WorkerThread implements Callable<Object> {
    ConsumerConnector consumerConnector;
    private static ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        processMsg();
        return list;
    }

    private void processMsg() {
        StringMessage msg = new StringMessage();
        Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        topicCountMap.put(KafkaConstants.LOB_TOPIC, new Integer(1));
        Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumerConnector
                .createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
        KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream = consumerMap.get(KafkaConstants.LOB_TOPIC).get(0);
        ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> itr = stream.iterator();

            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                msg.setMessage(new String((itr.next().message())));
                list.add(msg);
                System.out.println("&&&" + msg);
            }

        System.out.println("++++++++++++");
    }
}
```

In the above sample, my `"++++++"` sysout is not working.. Anyone knows the cause..?

Comment: is there &&& printing ?  is there any error ?

Comment: The `+++` does not work, but what _does_ happen? Does the `&&&` loop output infinitely or not process at all or...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson if there is one message &&& prints one message then it stops..No exception at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The KafkaStream is blocking.

See

http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/131nb67cvk/non-blocking-kafka-stream-iterators

Comment: Can you explain bit more? Im new to Kafka.Im trying to return object array from java thread to my message listener, which will spawn new threads (the above sample code) using executor

Comment: you can change the timeout of the blocking in the propertyconsumer.timeout.ms

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449851/kafka-consumer-hanging-at-hasnext-in-java