# Get all kafka messages in a queue and stop streaming in java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to execute a Job at night that is going to get all the messages in a kafka queue and execute a process with them. I'm able to get the messages but the kafka stream is waiting for more messages and I'm not able to continue with my process. I have the following code:

```
...
private ConsumerConnector consumerConnector;
private final static String TOPIC = "test";

public MessageStreamConsumer() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
        properties.put("group.id", "test-group");
        ConsumerConfig consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig(properties);
        consumerConnector = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(consumerConfig);
    }
public List<String> getMessages() {
                Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                topicCountMap.put(TOPIC, new Integer(1));
                Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumerConnector
                        .createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
                KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream = consumerMap.get(TOPIC).get(0);
                ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
                List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
                while (it.hasNext())
                    messages.add(new String(it.next().message()));
                return messages;
            }
```

The code is able to get the messages but when it process the last message it stays in the line:

```
 while (it.hasNext())
```

The question is, how can i get all the messages from the kafka, stop the stream and continue with my other tasks.

I hope you can help me

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka Consumer hanging at .hasNext in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449851/kafka-consumer-hanging-at-hasnext-in-java)

Comment: But I don't think that the best practice to do this is to wait until an exception is thrown. What if my process take more time that the timeout configured

Comment: Shouldn't you use a straight up Kafka Consumer here, instead of a KafkaStream? A stream would naturally stay alive.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that kafka stream does not support to consume from beginning.
You could create a native kafka consumer and set `auto.offset.reset` to earliest, then it will consume message from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work. Basically the idea is to use a Kafka Consumer and poll until you get some record and then stop when you get an empty batch.

```
package kafka.examples;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;


public class Consumer1 extends Thread
{
    private final KafkaConsumer<Integer, String> consumer;
    private final String topic;
    private final DateFormat df;
    private final String logTag;
    private boolean noMoreData = false;
    private boolean gotData = false;
    private int messagesReceived = 0;
    AtomicBoolean isRunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    CountDownLatch shutdownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public Consumer1(Properties props)
    {
        logTag = "Consumer1";

        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        this.topic = props.getProperty("topic");
        this.df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(this.topic));
    }

    public void getMessages() {
        System.out.println("Getting messages...");
        while (noMoreData == false) {
            //System.out.println(logTag + ": Doing work...");

            ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
            Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            int recordsCount = records.count();
            messagesReceived += recordsCount;
            System.out.println("recordsCount: " + recordsCount);
            if (recordsCount > 0) {
               gotData = true;
            }

            if (gotData && recordsCount == 0) {
                noMoreData = true;
            }

            for (ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> record : records) {
                int kafkaKey = record.key();
                String kafkaValue = record.value();
                System.out.println(this.df.format(now) + " " + logTag + ":" +
                        " Received: {" + kafkaKey + ":" + kafkaValue + "}" +
                        ", partition(" + record.partition() + ")" +
                        ", offset(" + record.offset() + ")");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Received " + messagesReceived + " messages");
    }

    public void processMessages() {
        System.out.println("Processing messages...");
    }

    public void run() {
        getMessages();
        processMessages();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently developing with Kafka 0.10.0.1 and found mixed information regarding the use of consumer property **auto.offset.reset** so I've done some experiments to figure out what actually happens.

Based on those, I now understand it this way: when you set property:

```
auto.offset.reset=earliest
```

this positions the consumer to EITHER the first available message in the partitions assigned (when no commits have been made on the paritions) OR it positions the consumer at the last committed partition offsets (notice that you always commit last read offset + 1 or else you'll be re-reading the last committed message on each restart of your consumer)

Alternatively you do not set **auto.offset.reset** which means default value of 'latest' will be used.

In that case you do not receive any old messages on connecting the consumer - only messages published to the topic after connecting the consumer will be received.

As a conclusion - if you want to ensure to receive all available messages for a certain topic and assigned partitions you'll have to call seekToBeginning().

It seems advised to call poll(0L) first to ensure your consumer gets partitions assigned (or implement your code in the ConsumerRebalanceListener!), then seek each of the assigned partitions to 'beginning':

```
kafkaConsumer.poll(0L);
kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning(kafkaConsumer.assignment());
```